# Why do I have to set targetCompatibility to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 if my JVM is 1.8

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jvm

[image]Hello in order to compile with a library im using they request that we set these settings.  But im confused because my machine is running JVM 1.8 and I seen other people mention that gradle uses the JVM thats currently running which for me is 1.8 ? so why do I have to set this setting ? am I missing something to my knowledge it should compile fine without setting this setting since I'm using JVM 8

Comment: You sound very convincing; why don't you try it?

Comment: I did try it and the build failed but Im confused why if my JVM is using 1.8 ? maybe you could help me out

Comment: You may be using Java 8, but other developers might not be if they're working on your code. How is the build system supposed to just infer that the original code was written for Java 8 and not a different version?

Comment: that makes sense